# Pandas add to list the combination of adjacent elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, data-manipulation

What I want to do seems simple, say I have an existing list of words:

```
original_List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to transform that list into:

```
new_List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a b', 'b c', 'c d']
```

So in the new list we took the original list and then appended to it 2 elements at a time.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: why the need to tag `pandas` here?

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
original_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

new_list = original_list + [f"{a} {b}" for a, b in zip(original_list, original_list[1:])]
print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a b', 'b c', 'c d']
```

Or, as an alternative, use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
from itertools import pairwise
new_list = original_list + [f"{a} {b}" for a, b in pairwise(original_list)]
print(new_list)
```

Comment: how can I apply approach # 1 if I have a dataframe with a column that has several "original lists" and I want to create a new column with the "Output List" that you have?